# Is there any reason to prepare Cure spells as a Cleric or Summon spells as a Druid in Pathfinder?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells, cleric, druid

I am just learning Pathfinder at the moment. As I understand it, instead of any spell Clerics prepared they may cast a spell with "Cure" in it's name if it is of the same level, Druids do the same with "Summon Nature's Ally" spells.

Why would one then prepare any such a spell normally? It seems like just wasting an opportunity to prepare something else.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Not all clerics can spontaneously cast *cure* spells—evil clerics and neutral clerics who choose to channel negative energy instead spontaneously cast *inflict* spells—but otherwise, you’re completely correct. The spontaneous spell class features of clerics and druids are there to *save you the trouble of preparing those spells*. You can prepare something else, and then if it turns out you need *cure* or *summon nature’s ally* more than that thing, you can still have it.

Do note, however, that every single *cure* or *inflict* spell is also much, much weaker than a typical spell of its level, and *summon nature’s ally*, while decently strong, has the large complication of having a “1 round” casting time (i.e. the summon does not appear until your next turn, and that only if nothing disrupts your concentration on the spell). This is likely an intentional trade-off for clerics and druids—you can get this spell exactly when you need it, but it’s not going to be “as good” in some general sense (as opposed to the specific situation you’re in) as whatever you are replacing.

There are two cases where you still could theoretically want to prepare spells you can cast spontaneously: metamagic and the healing domain. If you know you will wish to use metamagic on a spell, it is better to prepare that spell with the metamagic than it is to spontaneously cast it with the metamagic, as the latter extends the casting time of the spell.<sup>1</sup> And domain spell slots cannot be spontaneously converted to *cure* or *inflict*, so for example if you channel positive energy and have the healing domain, for most domain slots, you have a choice between a *cure* spell, or another spell that will not be eligible to convert to *cure* later. Ultimately, though, these are both kind of moot points—the *cure* spells are so bad that you shouldn’t waste spell slots trying to metamagic them, nor should you take the Healing Domain.

(It is because of this weakness of the *cure* spells that it’s also good to buy a *wand of cure light wounds* to heal in between combats—it’s the most efficient healing in the game,<sup>2</sup> it preserves your best spell slots for better things than *cure* spells, and between combats you’ll usually have the time you need to zap the wand several times. Many clerics only use their spontaneous *cure* ability in dire emergencies. It’s only once you get the fantastic *heal* spell that healing in-combat becomes something worth doing even when not absolutely forced to.)

1. <sub>In the case of *cure* or *inflict*, this makes the spellcasting take your entire turn; in the case of *summon nature’s ally*, it makes the summoning take **two** entire rounds so by the time you get the thing, the fight is probably pretty much over. Note that there is a difference between a “full-round action” casting time, as with the spontaneously-metamagic’d *cure*, and a “1 round” casting time, as is the case for *summon nature’s ally*—the former takes your entire turn but still happens on your turn, while the latter takes your entire turn as well all the time until the beginning of your next one, making you vulnerable to disruption and delaying the actual effect of the spell.</sub>
2. <sub>That is, in terms of hp healed per gp spent, and actually that’s not quite true as a caster level 1st *cure light wounds* will heal 2-9 hp (average 4.5), while a caster level 1st *infernal healing* will heal 10 hp (over the course of 1 minute). But *infernal healing* causes alignment problems for a lot of parties/clerics, and *celestial healing* is complete garbage thanks to its duration of 1 round/2 levels.</sub>

Comment: You say that *Infernal Healing* is the best -- isn't *Celestial Healing* just as good, given that all I need to cast it is just a Good complementary of what's needed for *Infernal Healing*?

Comment: @Baskakov_Dmitriy *Infernal healing* is the most healing available from a 1st-level spell slot (1 hp/round for 1 minute = 10 hp healed; cf. *cure light wounds* with an average of 9.5 hp healed at caster level 5th). Meanwhile, *celestial healing* has doesn’t last as long as *infernal healing* until caster level **20th**. *Celestial healing* is garbage.

Comment: You could, plausibly, want to prepare a spell you can cast spontaneously in order to prepare it with a metamagic effect without suffering the normal extra casting time. It's also important to remember that the domain spell slots that clerics get cannot be used to spontaneously cast, and if you have the healing domain (for instance), the various cure spells are one of only two spells you'd be able to use in most of those slots.

Comment: @Carcer Healing domain indeed makes using Cure spells way better starting at 6th level and domain spells are all Cure. But there is still no reason to fill your spell slots with Cure spells, because you can cast the, spontaneously anyway with the same +50% to power. The metamagic effects may probably worth it, I didn't study them yet, but likely that not for a low level Cleric.

Comment: @Baskakov_Dmitriy Actually, Empower Spell is not sufficient to make the *cure* spells actually good. Numbers just don’t work out in their favor; you end up spending your entire turn (not to mention the spell slot) healing about one attack’s worth of damage—but characters can easily have multiple attacks per turn by 6th level. And since the Healing Domain also represents the loss of an opportunity to get spells you couldn’t otherwise cast (since many domains offer such spells and Healing has none), it isn’t recommended.

Comment: @Carcer You do bring up good points—even though you *shouldn’t* waste your resources by using metamagic on *cure* spells or taking the Healing Domain, you *can* and it’s worth covering those possibilities in the answer.

Comment: It's interesting to see the math of healing's inefficiency laid out, does anyone have a resource (other question, forum, etc) that it's further explained?

Comment: @Ifusaso Quick back-of-the-envelope thing is comparison with sneak attack: at any given level, sneak attack deals a number of d6 dice equal to the number of d8 dice in the highest-level *cure* spell available. The larger die and the addition of caster level to the healing represents another 1.5 healing/level. Thus, sneak attack averages to 1.75 damage/level, while casting the highest-available *cure* spell averages 3.25/level. At best (ignoring the weapon itself as well as the rogue’s Strength or other features), that cancels two attacks. But rogues have two attacks from 1st (TWF) and get more

Comment: @KRyan Seems like your last sentence is incomplete, or am I wrong?

Comment: @Baskakov_Dmitriy No, that was the end (period eaten by the comment length-limit). I was saying that rogues get two attacks already at 1st level, and go up from there, so healing *almost* two attacks’ worth of damage is a losing battle. And that’s sneak attack, a relatively inefficient approach to damage. More damage-focused characters can do much, *much* better than the rogue can. If, each round, your turn undoes less than one enemy turn, you are by definition accomplishing less for your team than that enemy is for his or her team, which is not a winning strategy—and then you run out of slots